# JavaScript RegExp Three Parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a help with regular expressions in JavaScript (Sorry, I'm still trying to learn it.).

I have the string: `value1 value2 (value3 value4) -value5 value6`
*(Can have infinite values ​​in each of three parts.)*

And I need to separate:

```
var1 = value1 + ' ' + value2 ...
var2 = value3 + ' ' + value4 ...
var3 = value5 + ' ' + value6 ...
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of a longer input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting may be an idea, if the formatting of the string stays like the given format:

```
'value1 value2 (value3 value4) -value5 value6'.split(/\s+\(|\)\s+\-/);
//=> ["value1 value2", "value3 value4", "value5 value6"]
```

Comment: Great! But the first value have a space at the end of the string. Any ideas for this? jQuery.trim()?

Comment: Hi Caio, glad I could help. I've edited the answer, the splitting now removes the space too.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original string already contains those space delimiters, try:

```
/^(.*) \((.*)\) -(.*)$/.exec(str);
```

It matches the string `"anything (anything) -anything"`.

It returns an array of which `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` contain the three results.

Note though that the values are not allowed to have the special characters in them (like `(` or `-` with a space prepended) otherwise the format is not really definable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str1 = "value1 value2 (value3 value4) -value5 value6";

//var parts = str1.match(/^([^(]+)\(\s?([^)]+)\)\s?(.+)$/);
var parts = str1.match(/^([^(]+)\(\s?([^)]+)\)\s?-(.+)$/);

var var1 = parts[1];
var var2 = parts[2];
var var3 = parts[3];

console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
console.log(var3);
```

Comment: I think you'd possibly need to include the dash.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about finding each part first, then split the values in each for more efficiency. Then I would stick them together using a single space. I used a lot of `\s*`'es because I'm assuming there might be multiple spaces (such as those in the commented line).

```
var str = 'value1 value2 (value3 value4) -value5 value6';
//var str = '  value1    value2 (   value3 value4)   -value5 value6 ';

var pairs = str.match(/^\s*(.+?)\s*\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\s*(.+?)\s*$/);

values1 = pairs[1].split(/\s+/);
values2 = pairs[2].split(/\s+/);
values3 = pairs[3].split(/\s+/);

console.log('values1:',values1,'-->',values1.join(' '));
console.log('values2:',values2,'-->',values2.join(' '));
console.log('values3:',values3,'-->',values3.join(' '));
```

**Explanation of RegEx**

- `^` beginning of string
- `\s*` possible empty spaces
- `(.+?)` a character group (at least 1 character)
- `\s*` possible empty spaces
- `\(` opening parantheses
- `\s*` possible empty spaces
- `(.+?)` a character group (at least 1 character)
- `\s*` possible empty spaces
- `\)` closing parantheses
- `\s*` possible empty spaces
- `(.+?)` a character group (at least 1 character)
- `\s*` possible empty spaces
- `$` end of string