# Break Apart string in JavaScript with three parts

Tags: javascript, regex, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript RegExp Three Parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758795/javascript-regexp-three-parts)

I need a help with regular expressions in JavaScript (Sorry, I'm still trying to learn it.).

I have this strings:

```
all (any) -del
all -del (any)
all (any)
all -del
all
```

PS: `all`, `any` and `del` can assume any value, including spaces.

And I need to separate each string:

```
var1 = all
var2 = any (or null)
var3 = del (or null)
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything relevant about the words being enclosed in parentheses `()`, or prefixed with a `-`?

Comment: Yes, they can assume any value, including spaces.

Comment: I already answered this once today...

Comment: Yep... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758795/javascript-regexp-three-parts/9758842#comment12416468_9758842

Comment: @epascarello same guy, same question

Comment: @epascarello, thanks for your response, but does not work in many cases, such as separation of a string that does not have some elements (in this case).

Comment: @epascarello, your response works perfectly to `all (any) -del` but not to `all -del`.

Comment: If "any value including spaces" includes the characters `(`, `)` and `-` then you're pretty S.O.L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
/^(.*?)\s?(\(.*?\)|)\s?(-.*?|)$/
```

application to your examples:

```
'all (any) -del'.match(/^(.*?)\s?(\(.*?\)|)\s?(-.*?|)$/)
["all (any) -del", "all", "(any)", "-del"]

'all (any)'.match(/^(.*?)\s?(\(.*?\)|)\s?(-.*?|)$/)
["all (any)", "all", "(any)", ""]

'all -del'.match(/^(.*?)\s?(\(.*?\)|)\s?(-.*?|)$/)
["all -del", "all", "", "-del"]

'all'.match(/^(.*?)\s?(\(.*?\)|)\s?(-.*?|)$/)
["all", "all", "", ""]
```

To process new requirement, a little bit complex:

```
'all (any) -del'.match(/^(.*?)(?:\s?(\([^-]*\)|)\s?(-[^()]*|)|\s?(-[^()]*|)\s?(\([^-]*\)|))$/)
["all (any) -del", "all", "(any)", "-del", undefined, undefined]
'all -del (any)'.match(/^(.*?)(?:\s?(\([^-]*\)|)\s?(-[^()]*|)|\s?(-[^()]*|)\s?(\([^-]*\)|))$/)
["all -del (any)", "all", undefined, undefined, "-del ", "(any)"]
```

Comment: Thanks man! Is possible to adapt this expression to also work with the string: `all -del (any)`?

Comment: @CaioTarifa: It's a little bit complex, see my edit.

Comment: Extremely complex! Even so, you came pretty close, thanks.